# I need help creating a monopoly board in java using for loops

Tags: java

I am trying to create a board for a java project in my cs class. I am rather confused on how to create a for loop that would successfully print out the elements of the board including the 11 by 11 frame.

```
import java.util.*;import java.util.*;
public class Board
{
    static String [][] board = new String [11][11];
    public Board ()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=11; i++){ 
            for(int j=0; j<=11;j++)
            {
                System.out.println("| |");
            }
            System.out.println("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Change `System.out.println("| |");` to `System.out.print("| |");` "println()" adds a linefeed; "print" continues on the same line.  2) If your array size is "11",and you only want to iterate 11 times, then change your loop to `for(int i=0; i<11; i++)`.  Looping i=0 to i <= 11 will iterate *12* times.

Comment: Add the desired output to your question.

Comment: You'll get there, we believe in you.  It might help us if you type out an example of what you wanted, though ;)

Comment: Thanks for all the help I actually need a board printed out since so far we have not covered java swing awt etc. I need a board that can be used and printed and out where I can add spaces and properties.

Comment: You need to show exactly what you want the board to look like.

Comment: A monopoly board is 10x10 spaces. If your going to show that in terminal of 80 characters wide the internal width of your spaces will be 8 spaces. Is 8x8 enough to print what you need to show? Property name + houses/hotel + maximum number of players on that space?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a first draft. I've created a three dimensional array which is the board which is 11x11 with 8 lines of 8 characters for each space. You need to implement a check that the length of each String is always 8 characters if you want your board to line up.

```java
class Monopoly{
    public static void main(String[] args){
// work on an 11 * 11 board
        String[][][] board = new String[11][11][8];
        board[0][0][1]="   GO   ";
        board[0][0][3]="COLLECT ";
        board[0][0][4]="  200$  ";
        board[0][10][0]="PRISON ";
        board[10][10][1]="  FREE  ";
        board[10][10][3]="PARKING ";
        board[10][0][1]=" GO TO  ";
        board[10][0][3]="  JAIL  ";
        showBoard(board);
    }
    public static void showBoard(String[][][] board){
        String fullLine="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
            System.out.println(fullLine);
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
                for(int k=0;k<11;k++){
                    if(board[i][k][j] == null){board[i][k][j]="        ";};
                    String s = board[i][k][j];
                    //if (length(s)=0 ){s="        ";};
                System.out.print("x" + s);
                }
                System.out.println("x");
            }
        }
         System.out.println(fullLine);
    }
        
}
```

Which gives the following result. (Illisible if the terminal is not wide enought).

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        xPRISON x
x   GO   x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xCOLLECT x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x  200$  x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x GO TO  x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x  FREE  x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x  JAIL  x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        xPARKING x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x        x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```